# UILocalnotification is not appearing when the application is in the background

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a monotouch application which has a timer and gets the data from the server.
Once the data is received i want to show the notification on the status bar.
It wrks fine when the app is in foreground. When the app is in background ,neither the timer nor the notification works

Please help me in rectifying this issue.

Comment: +1, really annoying and there's no very well designed solution.

Answer (score 1):

getting you app to run in the background is easy, add App registers for location updates in the info.plist, create a CLlocation singleton register for significant location change and you are done, your app will be resurrected every time there is a significant location change

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brett ... But how about the situation where i keep my phone in the same location(Say, there is no location change)... Will my app run on the background ?

Comment: well from what i know and understand, it will run in the background for a limited and undefined amount of time then it will get to the suspended stage and then dye... lol http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html but there a other background modes that you can subscribe to, sorry i dont have an answer for you...

Answer (score 0):

When an iOS app transitions to the suspended (i. e. backgrounded) state, it stops its timers and disables locl notifications (and does some more memory optimization-related actions). A possible solution (JB only) to display user alerts while your app is in the background is to run a server (true unix server which is not bothered by an app getting backgrounded!) and use the undocumented CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert() function (just google it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is that the only way ?? What to do if i want to alert the user when the app is in background ?

Comment: Sorry, but Apple is restrictive. There's this undocumented method that you can use and that has been there/working for ages, but your app is deíactivated when it's put in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is to extend the lifetime of your app by a little bit, by requesting a grace period in the background.   As long as you receive this message during this time frame, you will be able to post the notification.

You do this by calling UIApplication.BeginBackgroundTask.   This will let you run for a little bit, and the method you pass will be invoked shortly before your grace period runs out.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an App with registers for location updates it seems to always run in the background to a certain extent, as you get significan location changes and you get the enter/exit regions, so you app is running code or is being waken up to run code... the problem is that the UILocalnotification doesn't trigger a sound and alert consitently ( but all the calls are displayed in the notification center... ) The big problem here is that the significan location changes, and the enter/exit regions are useless if you can not notify your user reliably.... is CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert() the only solution to trigger an alert to the user... ? does it work ? will your app be rejected if you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working as follows :(Not a good design, but a working one)
Addded location support in info.plist, create a clocation manager and kept on requsting the location services. On the same loop schedule the UIlocalnotification .

It works perfectly. :)

NOTE : One issue is that it will give the user a propmpt as "This app uses your location, Do you want o allow"