# Iphone presentLocalNotificationNow not triggering alert and sound while app in background

Tags: ios, uialertview, uilocalnotification

I have an App registers for location updates, running tests, sometime when I enter a region while the app is in the background I receive a alarm notification with sound. sometime I only see the notification in notification center, and i did not receive any sound and alert... 
What can you do to always get the sound and the alert notification ?

this is what i have in my view

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotif.fireDate             = nil;
 localNotif.hasAction            = YES;
 localNotif.alertBody            = fbName;
 localNotif.alertAction          = @"View";
 localNotif.soundName            = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
```

and this is the app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification (UILocalNotification *)notification
{
if (notification) 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                    message:notification.alertBody
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [alertView show];

}

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];

UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (notification) 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [alertView show];

}



return YES;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILocalnotification is not appearing when the application is in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367400/uilocalnotification-is-not-appearing-when-the-application-is-in-the-background)

Comment: I don't think this is quite the same, as it works in some cases, it seems to have something to do with the time it has been in the background for me, it revolve around the state of the application when its in the background and the UILocalNotification behavior appears to be inconsistent anyone experience this ?

Answer (score 3):

If the application is running in the background, the local notification will not get an alert or sound, as it is directly received by your application. In that case, you need to present the notification using `presentLocalNotificationNow`.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState applicationState = application.applicationState;
    if (applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        [application presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to call presentLocalNotificationNow. This is for posting a Local Notification Immediately. You'd likely get an endless loop here I believe.

Comment: `presentLocalNotificationNow:` only presents a local notification, it does not re-post it.