# Local Notifications not trigering alert consitently

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

> Scheduling the Delivery of Local Notifications
>
> Notifications are a way for an app that is suspended, is in the
>   background, or is not running to get the user’s attention. Apps can
>   use local notifications to display alerts, play sounds, badge the
>   app’s icon, or a combination of the three.

from the apple docs: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

but from my experience the localNotification does not alway wake up the app or play the alert/sound when the app is in the background or suspended has anyone found a way to alway notify the user consistently ?

Comment: Do you have any sample code which show this behavior?

Comment: actually i do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369945/iphone-presentlocalnotificationnow-not-triggering-alert-and-sound-while-app-in-b